# Jquery check if checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somthing is wrong with this code.

I have div box and when click on Coutries title he shows the list of countries.
that list contain 5 check box

- Germania
- USA
- Serbia
- France

Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/ikac/bfaH5/

I have problem when i try to check if some countury checked..

```
   searchContainer: function() {

        var title = $(".title-search");

         // On click show countury list 

        title.click(function(){                  
                $(".state").fadeToggle('fast',function(){

                    // check if sothing checked

                    if ($("#france").is(':checked')) {
                        alert("France Selected");

                        // Show all cities from this countury
                    }

                });
        });
    }
```

But when i check a country nothing happens....

First time i try this:

```
if($("#france").checked = true)) {
     alert("FRANCE");
}
```

But when i click on title and when fadeToggle is done he show alert(FRANCE) whitout checking.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/gfactory.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gfactory.css">
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                window.Balcanrent.init();
                window.Balcanrent.searchContainer();
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form name="search">

            <div class="search-box"> 
                <div class="title-search"> Counturies </div>
                <div class="state">
                    <ul class="s_list">
                        <li><input id="ger" type="checkbox" value="gr">Germania</li>
                        <li><input id="usa" type="checkbox" value="usa">USA</li>
                        <li><input id="sr" type="checkbox" value="sl"> Serbia </li>
                        <li><input id="france" type="checkbox" value="fr">France </li>
                    </ul>                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And i try to use .length > 0 but nothing again. What i do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: try :

document.getElementById("checkboxid").checked property of JS.

Comment: [`jQuery.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/check) is the correct way to determine if a checkbox is checked (see my answer).

Comment: Nope this dont work on my code

Comment: It would help if you made a JSFiddle of your example so everyone could see exactly what you're trying

Comment: Here is my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ikac/bfaH5/

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer to use the CSS selector approach, you can do this:

```
var c = $('#france').is(":checked");
```

Or:

```
var c = $('#france').prop("checked");
```

.prop() is probably the better choice.

From here:  http://api.jquery.com/prop/ - is() and prop(), while they retrieve different things, both work reliably.  While using attr() has a different meaning - it retrieves only the default value

Comment: @jahroy I didn't copy your answer, was providing more explanation.  But you're right, I did screw it up the first time, it's right now.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle here for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/kyawsithu/shC3c/1/

Below code you used for checking the Checkbox checked property is correct.

```
    if ($("#france").is(':checked')) {
        alert("France Selected");
    }
```

EDIT: When you click again on **Countries** when **States** fade in, the checked is still true and it shows the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help you..

```
   var title = $(".title-search");

   title.click( function(){ 
    var selected = '';
    $('.s_list input:checked').each(function() {
     selected += $(this).attr('id') +  ',';
      }); 
         $(".state").fadeToggle('fast');
        if(selected.length)
            alert('selected: ' + selected);
    });
```